# Can't push or pull to Github

Tags: git, github, push

When I try and pull:

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

When I try a push or a `push -u origin master`:

```
master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading through the "man git-push" they mention a "git pull" should be enough to resolve this, but since you're getting "error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied" did you perhaps create the clone of the branch using sudo ? If so your files may not be readable by your user. Double check that the file .git/FETCH_HEAD is readable by your user account.

Comment: I cloned using sudo, I just rest everything and setup a new repo. Job done!

Answer (score 3):

Your local copy might not be in-sync with the remote hub.

Here is a good guideline when pulling/pushing from/to github repo:

1. git stash - to make sure your changes are stash and your copy is reverted to the last commit that is in-sync with the remote.
2. git pull  - pull changes from remote
3. git stash pop - to merge your changes to latest source code
4. git mergetool - if there are conflicts, you need to do this before the changes are merged.
5. git commit - to commit your changes in your local repo
6. git push  - to push your changes to remote.